# Can you recommend a better alternative to this regex?

Tags: c#, regex

```
private const string NUMERIC_REGEX = "\\W*([0-9]+)(\\W)?([0-9]*)\\W*"
```

I found this regex being used in a project I'm working on. It's suppose to parse the number from a string that contains a currency.

Like "14.22 €" => 14.22

But it doesn't seem to support this. Can someone help me adapt it to also work with special currency symbols?

As an alternative I found this `([\d,.]+)` to work fine for what I need, but I'm not sure if I'm missing out any special cases, or maybe it's too generic.

Comment: It's not always in this format, the currency sign can go left or right, with or without space

Comment: Try [`\p{Sc}*\s*([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)\s*\p{Sc}*`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cp%7bSc%7d*%5cs*%28%5b0-9%5d*%5c.%3f%5b0-9%5d%2b%29%5cs*%5cp%7bSc%7d*&i=Like+%2214.22+%e2%82%ac%22) where `\p{Sc}` matches the currency symbols. Use it as `private const string NUMERIC_REGEX = @"\p{Sc}*\s*([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)\s*\p{Sc}*";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good answer to your question would be to use the regex:

```
(?:\p{Sc} ?)?([\d,.]+)(?: ?\p{Sc})?
```

[Regex Proof](https://regex101.com/r/FqKYbW/1)

This regex is just an extended version of the regex you were using.
What it does is it checks for an optional currency symbol before AND after your number.

The magic for matching a currency symbol is \p{Sc} as you can find [here](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/pcresyntax/), and an optional space.

This regex checks for the currency symbols in a non-capturing group, meaning capturing group 1 will be your number.

For more explanation just click the Regex Proof link in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

well I don't know if you would like to use a existing class, but you might want to try out System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlMoney... This will make sure your string is not just parsed by some regexp which might fail...

Use would be like:

```
SqlMoney money = SqlMoney.Parse("12,03 €");
decimal number = money.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this ? :

```
const string PATTERN = @"^(?'num'\d{0,}[\.|,]{0,1}\d{0,})";
```

[online regex](https://regex101.com/r/Ng3umP/1)

You can use this like:

```
match = regex.Match(meInput);
string numStr = match.Groups["num"].Value;
double num = double.Parse(numStr);
```